# Asynchronous method not running in parallel

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have `Service.class` with `start()` and `asychronous()` method :

```
    public ResponseEntity<Object> start() throws APICommandConstructionException, APICommunicationException, APIReplyParseException,
            APIErrorResponse, IOException {

        List<Company> companiesList = dbHandler.retrieveCompaniesList();

        Company company = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < companiesList.size(); i++) {
            asychronousMethod(companiesList, i, company);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Start method has Finished", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public void asychronousMethod(List<Company> companiesList, int i, Company company) throws APICommandConstructionException, APIReplyParseException, APICommunicationException, APIErrorResponse, IOException {
        company = companiesList.get(i);
        company = utils.websiteScrap(company);
        companiesRepository.save(company);
    }
```

Everything that is inside a loop doesn't run in parallel, but it starts second loop after first finished. Why is that? How to do it parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief: you shouldn't call explicitly methods with Spring annotations.

More detailed:
Spring creates special proxies that on back-stage do 'magic' for you. So if you have async annotation, that means that (depending on compile- and runtime-configuration of Spring) there was some hidden part of code that is not executed when you invoke `this.asynchronousMethod`.

How to fix:

First of all method should match  `public CompletableFuture<Void>` - such way you know when thread is complete.

Second instead of `this` you need resolve self-instance as Spring proxy.
The simplest way over `@Autowired`:

```
@Autowired
MyClass zhis;

.... //in for loop:
future = zhis.asychronousMethod(companiesList, i, company);
```

P.s please see good example at https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: Its still doesnt work as expected in my case. It blocks for one thread after another in sequence and finally the caller finishes when all async threads are returned. Anything to add ?

Comment: @KnockingHeads - please give me more details by asking a new question. You even may post a link there so I will be able to take a look.